# knnx.index() function returning Data:non-numeric in r on r shiny webapp

Tags: r, shiny, knn

I am building a webapp on the r shiny platform. I am letting the user select a soccer player, and trying to make the output show 10 more players with similar attributes. I created a subset for the selected players data and another for the players not selected. Everything runs error free until I get to the knnx.index() where I am trying to find the 10 players whose attributes are closest to the selected player. Every time I do this however, I get the error: Data non-numeric. I checked if the subsets were made properly and the rbind worked properly and the all did. The error seems to stem from the knnx.index() function.

Please, any help would be much appreciated! Here is my code:

```
function(input, output, session) {
   
     selectedData1 <- reactive({
       
       filter(data,data$player != input$player)
     })
     
     
    selectedData2 <- reactive({
      selectedData1() %>%
        select(10,15,11,6,5,19,29,61,35,40,47,55,62,60) #%>%
        filter(league %in% input$league) %>%
        filter(Age >= input$age[1]) %>%
        filter(Age <= input$age[2]) %>%
        filter(Min >= input$minutes[1])  %>%
        filter(Min <= input$minutes[2])
    })
    
    selectedData3 <- reactive({
      data %>%
        select(10,15,11,6,5,19,29,61,35,40,47,55,62,60) %>%
        filter(data$player == input$player)

    })

    selectedData4 <- reactive({
      rbind(selectedData3(),selectedData2())

    })

    selectedData5 <- reactive({
      selectedData4() %>%
      select(6:14)
    })

    selectedData6 <- reactive({
      as.numeric(knnx.index(selectedData5(), selectedData5()[1, , drop=FALSE], k=11))
    })

    selectedData7 <- reactive({
      selectedData4()[selectedData6(),]
    })

    selectedData8 <- reactive({
      selectedData7() %>%
        select(6:14)
    })


    # Combine the selected variables into a new data frame
  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({

    validate(
      # need(dim(selectedData2())[1]>=10, "Sorry, no ten similar players were found.
      #      Please change the input filters."
      # )
       )

    plot_ly(
      type = 'scatterpolar',
      mode = "closest",
      fill = 'toself'
    ) %>%
      add_trace(
        r = as.matrix(selectedData8()[1,]),
        theta = c("TouchIndex","PassIndex","PostRecFwdPass","Creation","Team Attack","Total Disruption","Ball Winning","Individual Defending","TeamDefending"),
        showlegend = TRUE,
        mode = "markers",
        name = selectedData7()[1,1]
      ) %>%
      add_trace(
        r = as.matrix(selectedData8()[2,]),
        theta = c("TouchIndex","PassIndex","PostRecFwdPass","Creation","Team Attack","Total Disruption","Ball Winning","Individual Defending","TeamDefending"),
        showlegend = TRUE,
        mode = "markers",
        visible="legendonly",
        name = selectedData7()[2,1]
      ) %>%
      add_trace(
        r = as.matrix(selectedData8()[3,]),
        theta = c("TouchIndex","PassIndex","PostRecFwdPass","Creation","Team Attack","Total Disruption","Ball Winning","Individual Defending","TeamDefending"),
        showlegend = TRUE,
        mode = "markers",
        visible="legendonly",
        name = selectedData7()[3,1]
      ) %>%
      add_trace(
        r = as.matrix(selectedData8()[4,]),
        theta = c("TouchIndex","PassIndex","PostRecFwdPass","Creation","Team Attack","Total Disruption","Ball Winning","Individual Defending","TeamDefending"),
        showlegend = TRUE,
        mode = "markers",
        visible="legendonly",
        name = selectedData7()[4,1]
      ) %>%
      add_trace(
        r = as.matrix(selectedData8()[5,]),
        theta = c("TouchIndex","PassIndex","PostRecFwdPass","Creation","Team Attack","Total Disruption","Ball Winning","Individual Defending","TeamDefending"),
        showlegend = TRUE,
        mode = "markers",
        visible="legendonly",
        name = selectedData7()[5,1]
      ) %>%
      add_trace(
        r = as.matrix(selectedData8()[6,]),
        theta = c("TouchIndex","PassIndex","PostRecFwdPass","Creation","Team Attack","Total Disruption","Ball Winning","Individual Defending","TeamDefending"),
        showlegend = TRUE,
        mode = "markers",
        visible="legendonly",
        name = selectedData7()[6,1]
      ) %>%
      add_trace(
        r = as.matrix(selectedData8()[7,]),
        theta = c("TouchIndex","PassIndex","PostRecFwdPass","Creation","Team Attack","Total Disruption","Ball Winning","Individual Defending","TeamDefending"),
        showlegend = TRUE,
        mode = "markers",
        visible="legendonly",
        name = selectedData7()[7,1]
      ) %>%
      add_trace(
        r = as.matrix(selectedData8()[8,]),
        theta = c("TouchIndex","PassIndex","PostRecFwdPass","Creation","Team Attack","Total Disruption","Ball Winning","Individual Defending","TeamDefending"),
        showlegend = TRUE,
        mode = "markers",
        visible="legendonly",
        name = selectedData7()[8,1]
      ) %>%
      add_trace(
        r = as.matrix(selectedData8()[9,]),
        theta = c("TouchIndex","PassIndex","PostRecFwdPass","Creation","Team Attack","Total Disruption","Ball Winning","Individual Defending","TeamDefending"),
        showlegend = TRUE,
        mode = "markers",
        visible="legendonly",
        name = selectedData7()[9,1]
      ) %>%
      add_trace(
        r = as.matrix(selectedData8()[10,]),
        theta = c("TouchIndex","PassIndex","PostRecFwdPass","Creation","Team Attack","Total Disruption","Ball Winning","Individual Defending","TeamDefending"),
        showlegend = TRUE,
        mode = "markers",
        visible="legendonly",
        name = selectedData7()[10,1]
      ) %>%
      add_trace(
        r = as.matrix(selectedData8()[11,]),
        theta = c("TouchIndex","PassIndex","PostRecFwdPass","Creation","Team Attack","Total Disruption","Ball Winning","Individual Defending","TeamDefending"),
        showlegend = TRUE,
        mode = "markers",
        visible="legendonly",
        name = selectedData7()[11,1]
      ) %>%
      layout(
        polar = list(
          radialaxis = list(
            visible = T,
            range = c(0,100)
          )
       ),

     showlegend=TRUE


      )

   })
   
}
```

Comment: Actually the error I am getting now is: Warning: Error in get.knnx: ANN: ERROR------->

Comment: Welcome to SO! In general, try to test your logic code outside of shiny to make sure that it works and then put it into shiny to deal with shiny issues. Also, please provide some example data so that we can help you, thanks!